# Multiple List on a single listview through different buttons

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to use multiple data on a single listview through different buttons, as from activity1 there are two buttons, if button1 is clicked on activity2 it shows different data and if button2 is clicked then diff data respectively

```
//main

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NEXT.class) );

        }


    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NEXT.class) );

        }
    });

}
}

//for second activity
public class NEXT extends ListActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.next);

    if (R.id.button1 == clicked)   //did onClick="clicked"
     {
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.acceptors)));
     }
     else
     {
         setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.donars)));
     }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `putExtra()` method of the `Intent` class. Put boolean extra in your `MainActivity` with key `acceptors`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NEXT.class).putExtra("acceptors", true);

            }


        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NEXT.class).putExtra("acceptors", false));

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Then in your `NEXT` activity, get intent, and check whether you get acceptors or donors:

```
public class NEXT extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.next);
        boolean isAcceptors = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("acceptors", false);

        if (isAcceptors)   //did onClick="clicked"
        {
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.acceptors)));
        }
        else
        {
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.donars)));
        }

   }
}
```

Comment: Err it may sounds stupid but can you have a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934688/while-displaying-a-listview-through-parse-coms-database-error-arrayadapter-cre

i guess you can help, i'm really desperate here but not getting the correct answer i think you can help :|