# While displaying a listview through parse.com's database error "arrayadapter.createviewfromresource"

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, parse-platform, android-arrayadapter

I'm creating an app in which through parse.com's table listview will fetch the data from the table where in the column DonAcc (for donar or acceptors) if donar then its user name will get in the listview for donars same for acceptors. while doing so i'm getting an error

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
 at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
 at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2045)
```

My table name for user info is "User" and the field DonAcc is in the table "Data"
here is the code

```
public class Donar_Acceptor_list extends Activity {
ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.donar_acceptor_list);
new RemoteDataTask().execute();
}

private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Donar_Acceptor_list.this);
mProgressDialog.setTitle("Parse.com Simple ListView Tutorial");
mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
mProgressDialog.show();
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Data");
query.orderByDescending("_created_at");
query.whereEqualTo("DonAcc", "donar");
try {
ob = query.find();
} catch (ParseException e) {
Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}
@Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);     
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Donar_Acceptor_list.this,
R.layout.donar_aceptor_discription);              
for (ParseObject names : ob) {
adapter.add((String) names.get("username"));
}
// Binds the Adapter to the ListView
listview.setAdapter(adapter);  
// Close the progressdialog
mProgressDialog.dismiss();
  // Capture button clicks on ListView items
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
int position, long id) {
Intent i = new Intent(Donar_Acceptor_list.this,
Donar_Acceptor_Discription.class);
i.putExtra("name", ob.get(position).getString("name").toString());
startActivity(i);
            }  });  }}}
```

// For description activity >>

```
  public class Donar_Acceptor_Discription extends Activity {
// Declare Variables
TextView txtname;
String name;
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.donar_aceptor_discription);
    txtname=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    name = i.getStringExtra("name");
    txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    txtname.setText(name); } }
```

Comment: So you have 2 different tables? One is User, which has a field called username, another is Data, which has a field DonAcc? Whats the relationship between these two tables? Does your Data table has the field called username? If not, why dont you make a field called username in your Data table?

Comment: no there is no field name username in table Data cause it already exists in User? they are connected beacuse usingfrom a signin activity all the info is entered and it got saved in two different tables.. what am i supposed to do than?

Comment: You need to connect Data and the User. You can do that in two different way, you can either connect them by doing `ParseObject data = new ParseObject("Data");
data.put("userId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
data.saveInBackground();` Or, you can connect them by parent child relationship, you can do `data.put("parent", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());`

Comment: Thanks! i did this and its still giving the same error :|

Comment: I'm really really waiting for your response !!

Comment: Can you screenshot your User and Data tables, and post it in the question above

Comment: Errr i'm unable to post the images as it need 10 reputations and i have only 3 :| i'm really stucked here :/

Comment: I have created username field in Data table as well, still not working but just tell me the way i'm using the query and listview adapter is right or not?? Thanks for your time !!

Comment: After changing it all and connecting the tables i'm still getting this exception

11-15 17:28:58.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10529): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 17:28:58.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10529): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-15 17:28:58.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10529):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
11-15 17:28:58.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10529):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
11-15 17:28:58.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10529):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2045)

:|