# Listview is not displaying the data

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform

i'm working on a project [While displaying a listview through parse.com's database error "arrayadapter.createviewfromresource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934688/while-displaying-a-listview-through-parse-coms-database-error-arrayadapter-cre) But its not working Ok so in order to get my mind clear i made another project to just simple check if it is working but my listview is not displaying the data, i have got the code from this site http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-simple-listview-tutorial/  every thing is exactly same but data is not displaying in the list. Please i'm badly stuck here and i really need some fast help. Waiting for some positive response !

//Main code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// Declare Variables
ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from listview_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Execute RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
}

// RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Parse.com Simple ListView Tutorial");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "Country");
        query.orderByDescending("_created_at");
        try {
            ob = query.find();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into an ArrayAdapter
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.single_item);
        // Retrieve object "name" from Parse.com database
        for (ParseObject country : ob) {
            adapter.add((String) country.get("name"));
        }
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        // Capture button clicks on ListView items
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        SingleItemView.class);
                // Pass data "name" followed by the position
                i.putExtra("name", ob.get(position).getString("name")
                        .toString());
                // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

```
public class SingleItemView extends Activity {
// Declare Variables
TextView txtname;
String name;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from singleitemview.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.single_item_view);

    // Retrieve data from MainActivity on item click event
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Get the name
    name = i.getStringExtra("name");

    // Locate the TextView in singleitemview.xml
    txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

    // Load the text into the TextView
    txtname.setText(name);

}
```

}

//main's xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

// For single item display

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5sp"
android:textSize="25sp" >
```

Comment: Although you copied the code from somewhere else, you still need to provide your current code and logcat

Comment: Have you tried debug your code, near `adapter.add((String) country.get("name"));` when the adapter is adding the data?

Comment: Just did but i'm not getting it, as i'm a beginner! i debug it but it stops !

Comment: Do you have any error in the `logcat` when running the program? Please post it if you have any

Comment: No there is no error its working fine but no data is displaying on the listview.

Comment: Just tell me is there any problem in the way i'm using query or using the listview?

Comment: I think the way you use listview and adapter is right, i think the problem lies in the doInBackground or adapter.add((String) country.get("name"));

Comment: Than what can i do to solve this?
i have tried every thing i can, there is no error so i can't understand what should i do next :/

Comment: i got the exception finally while working on the main project

Comment: 11-15 17:28:58.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10529): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 17:28:58.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10529): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-15 17:28:58.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10529):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
11-15 17:28:58.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10529):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
11-15 17:28:58.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10529):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2045)